# Como converter de Timestamp para Calendar?

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo, calendar, timestamp, resultset

Preciso converter um `resultSet` do banco que retorna em `Timestamp` em uma variável do tipo Calendar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível em [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) você informar o *time*, que recebe uma instância de [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Como [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) é subclasse de [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), você pode fazer algo deste tipo:

```
public static Calendar timestampToCalendar(final Timestamp timestamp) {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(timestamp);
    return cal;
}
```